# Why do I get a blank output when I try to print ASCII table by array approach in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, casting, ascii

Writing a program to print the ASCII values of all 256 characters.

```
    int digit[] = new int[256];
    char array[] = new char[256];

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        array[i] = (char) digit[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

I get a blank output when I run this code.

Comment: Replace `array[i] = (char) digit[i]` with `array[i] = (char) i`

Comment: Considering you're not initialising `digit[]` with any values before you read them into `array[]`, why do you expect the output *not* to be blank?

Comment: Mr. Nitpicker writes: ASCII is a 7 bit code; codepoints > 127 are not ASCII.   Also, this is Java, so a `char` is a 16-bit Unicode (specifically UTF-16) value. Codepoints 0-127 are identical to ASCII; beyond that, see Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't initialize them, all the elements in `digit` are `0`, and ASCII `0` is the null character.

TO be honest, you don't need an array there - just iterate over them numbers 0 to 255 and print their cast to `char`s:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    System.out.println(i + " -- " + ((char)i)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell how should I have initialized the array to get the desired output?

Comment: @VaishakhYKumar you could loop over `digits` and initialized it - `for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {digits[i] = i;}`

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `int digit[]`. You only need to loop from 0 to 255 and cast each `int` to a char.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    array[i] = (char) i;
}
```

Alternatively, you can write a `for` loop using `char`.

```
for (char i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```